# Last modied by detail for a file using SVNkit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

Hi how to get the last modified by value for a file using SVNkit.
Scenario : the file is updated from SVN and itr is available in local repo(working copy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SVNProperties props=new SVNProperties();
    repository.getFile(filePath,new Long(-1),props,null);
    String author=props.getSVNPropertyValue("svn:entry:last-author").toString();
```

is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use svn keywords http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html 'modified by' should be author.

You have to ensure, that the file with the keywords will be changed before every check in. This could be done with an ant script.

The keyword could be used in a constant with a second constant extracting the interesting part:

```
private static final String SVN_AUTHOR_BASE            = "$Author: 113665 $";

/** Is filled in automatically on check in */
public static final String  SVN_AUTHOR                 = SVN_AUTHOR_BASE.
                              substring(9,SVN_AUTHOR_BASE.indexOf('$', 9) - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getLastModifiedBy(File localPath) throws SVNException {
    final SVNStatus status = SVNClientManager.newInstance().getStatusClient().doStatus(localPath, false);
    return status != null ? status.getAuthor() : null;
}
```